# Sends & Receive objects Over the network multiple times

Tags: java, java-me, io

I know how to send objects over the network using the serialization. My code basically using input and output streams through client socket.

For example:

•server sends objects

```
   •after sending :shutdown output for client socket
```

•Client read objects

```
   •after reading :shutdown input for client socket
```

•Client send data

```
   •after sending :shout down output
```

•Server read objects

```
   •after reading : shutdown input
```

•server send -------cannot because client socket close output channel to let the client send objects....

the core problem when I use shutdown and I want to be able to read or write again. I cannot read or write again, so how I can reopen it again ?

Is there is simple solution using serialization?

Comment: Erm, don't close the connection if you still want to use it.

Comment: If I did not close the connection it is not possible to send replay from the client to the server , so I must close the channel from one of them.

Comment: Huh? I think you're kinda confused. You probably want to start with a tutorial on sockets - Oracle's is here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: I mean by close connection to close input output channels from one client socket to let the other client socket read or write and versa... but Now that is possible only to read & write one time from each of them... cause I use after reading shutdown input  and after writing shutdown output for each of them.... Now how I can re -open the channel  again ?

Comment: Simply don't use the "shutdown input" and "shutdown output" here. There is no reason for them.

Comment: Is it possible to provide simple code of send multiple times from client and server ?... because when I try to not use shutdown or using reset , it is not working ..the client and server in waiting state..